# PHP cURL only returns small parts of the website

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to scrape this url

```
https://www.google.com/
```

With this code

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if($output === FALSE){
    echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
print_r($output);
?>
```

My problem is, the only thing I get in [return(image of display)](https://gyazo.com/f3a098876db75fd91b15d2c532bb8c85) is the `<ul class="breadcrumbs">` from the website among some other empty elements. No errors at all.

Comment: The site is likely rendering/loading content via JS/AJAX. CURL will get you only the raw base source file, it doesn't execute JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be ok, it fetches the url's content, but the better way to display it is this one:

```
echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars(print_r($output, 1))."</pre>";
```

All the data you see on the page is initially stored in JS:

```
 window.PRODUCT_PAGE_PROPS = ...
```

and then rendered to HTML by React. So to extract the data you first should  find the `script` block with regular expressions and then parse it's content.